# How to return words with specific letter in python

Tags: python

I need help with python code and Im beginner. I need to return words with specific letter. This is my try. I need to return words that includes letter "E"

```
lib = ["politsei", "mehine","panda","ment","kusi", "treener","leidma", "jooks", "muksid","president"]

def sisend(lib, b):
   print(lib)
     for i in lib:
        print(i)

    if e in lib:
        return lib
```

Comment: You are returning the entire list as soon as you find a value with e. You need to make another list and append it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` for this purpose

```
lib = ["politsei", "mehine","panda","ment","kusi", "treener","leidma", "jooks", "muksid","president"]

res = list(filter(lambda x:'e' in x, lib))
print(res)

# output ['politsei', 'mehine', 'ment', 'treener', 'leidma', 'president']
```

in your code, when you are iterating through each elemet of list, you need to check the word in that element not in list, if found then add that to orignal list

```
lib = ["politsei", "mehine","panda","ment","kusi", "treener","leidma", "jooks", "muksid","president"]

def sisend(lib, b):   
    result  =[]
    for i in lib:       
        if b in i:
            result.append(i)
    return result

print(sisend(lib, 'e'))

# output ['politsei', 'mehine', 'ment', 'treener', 'leidma', 'president']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
lib = ["politsei", "mehine","panda","ment","kusi", "treener","leidma", "jooks", "muksid", "president"]
for i in lib:
    if 'e' in i:
        print('e in word',i)
```

Please ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner solution

```
lib = ["politsei", "mehine","panda","ment","kusi", "treener","leidma", "jooks", "muksid",
"president"]

print(lib)
print([x for x in lib if 'e' in x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an introduction to functional programming and using a filter. Filters operate with a predicate (meaning a function which returns a boolean answer) for each position in the list. This predicate determines if we should keep the element at that position (let's call it *x*) in the list.

Therefore we could use a small function like this:

```
lambda x: 'e' in x
```

To determine which words we can keep.

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: 'e' in x, lib)))
```

But why stop there? We can generalize this! Say now that we have a function which works for 'e's why not make it work for any word we give it?

We can do this by composing our existing function with another function:

```
str_finder = lambda word: print(list(filter(lambda x: word in x, lib)))
```

Now I can do it for any word I want:

```
str_finder("mehine")
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, If words include letter "E" then I need to return these words and another words I need to print out. And I need to reverse returned words.

lib = ["politsei", "mehine","panda","ment","kusi", "treener","leidma", "jooks", "muksid","president"]

```
def sisend(lib, b):   

  result  =[]

      for i in lib:       
       if b in i:
        result.append(i)
     return result

   print(sisend(lib, 'e'))
```